# Keep equal space between x axis values of matplotlib scatter plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am struggling with the x ticks of a scatter plot.
I have a df with 3 columns and I want to plot them in a scatter plot.
The third column shall be used as a category.
The x values change their size according to 2^n (n are integer).
So my values for the x axis go from 1 to 4194304 and most of the x values are very small compared to max(x). This leads to the problem that most of the values are "pressed" in the left corner of the scatter plot and for the lower x values you cannot see anything.

I am looking for a way that the range between my x values will keep being the same independent of their actual size.

Here is what I have so far:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlabel='NumThreadsPerBlock*NumBlocksPerGrid',ylabel='EvtsPerSec[MatrixElems]')
plt.xticks(Data2['NumThreadsPerBlock*NumBlocksPerGrid'],rotation=75)
plt.title('check.exe itscrd02',loc='left')

for k,d in Data2.groupby('NumThreadsPerBlock'):
    ax.scatter(d['NumThreadsPerBlock*NumBlocksPerGrid'],d['EvtsPerSec[MatrixElems] (3)'],label=k,s=k,alpha=0.2)
    ax.legend(loc='lower right')
```

[image: Here is my scatter plot]

[This is the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XAw7.png)

Comment: You could set the x-axis in logscale via `ax.set_xscale('log')`. The code could further be simplified via seaborn's [scatterplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) using 'NumThreadsPerBlock' for the dot size.

Comment: Please [don't post your data as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Hi JohanC, thank you for the given hints. The ax.set_xscale('log') command gave me already a very good approach. I also tried seaborn and I think I'll keep using it. Sorry for posting my data as image. Next time I'll provide the data differently.

Comment: If your question has been solved now, you could close the post. Seaborn is a library that builds on matplotlib and pandas. A lot of standard plots can be created more easily with Seaborn; matplotlib can be used to make adaptions.